# Why are there two types of ICMP Redirect?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, icmp

Wikipedia lists 4 types of ICMP Redirect reasons:

```
0   Redirect for Network
1   Redirect for Host
2   Redirect for Type of Service and Network
3   Redirect for Type of Service and Host
```

I understand the purpose of ICMP Redirect, but why is there a need to distinguish between, say, a Network and a Host?

Comment: Granularity, the possibility that single hosts might have different policies than others, or the network as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [RFC 1812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812#section-4.3.3.2), there is a section about ICMP redirect that make your problem becomes clearly. Like this:

> If the directly connected network is not subnetted (in the
> classical sense), a router can normally generate a network
> Redirect that applies to all hosts on a specified remote network.
> Using a network rather than a host Redirect may economize slightly
> on network traffic and on host routing table storage.  However,
> the savings are not significant, and subnets create an ambiguity
> about the subnet mask to be used to interpret a network Redirect.
> In a CIDR environment, it is difficult to specify precisely the
> cases in which network Redirects can be used.  Therefore, routers
> must send only host (or host and type of service) Redirects.

Best regards.